# Filter a Listview with a combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, visual-studio-2012, combobox, filtering

What i want is mostly to hide arrays not requeries. So i have a combobox and listbox with values from database done by adapter , dataset , datatable and binding source. . SO when the person change the combobox values it would filter the list .So lets say to combobox is containing the ID so the list view will show those rows with that id. Onload the listview shows all properties . So how do you do this without Requery ???? So below i have the populating list and combobox part.

here is a link but its not very helpfull
   [VB.NET Listview Multiple Column Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976557/vb-net-listview-multiple-column-filter)

```
   Dim listcount As Integer = listview1.Columns.Count

    With listview1
        .Columns.Clear()
        .View = View.Details


        .GridLines = True


        .Columns.Add("Name").Width = 70
        .Columns.Add("ID").Width = 60
        .Columns.Add("Number").Width = 90


    End With


    Try


        strQuery = "Select * From Table"



        DB.Connection = New SqlConnection(strConnection)

        DB.Connection.Open()
        ' add a daaset
       Adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, DB.Connection)
        ListRS = New DataSet



        Adapter.Fill(ListRS)

        Dim table As DataTable = ListRS.Tables(0)


        bnsrc = New BindingSource
        bnsrc.DataSource = ListRS.Tables(0)
        combobox1.DataSource = bnsrc
         combobox1.DisplayMember = "ID"
        combobox1.ValueMember = "ID"
        combobox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems

       Listview1.Items.Clear()



        DB.Connection.Close()
```

So if i we to do requery it would be the same ust change the sql statement .

```
      strQuery =  "Select * from Table Where ID=@id"
```

IF i added a parameter how ever it would effect the combobx because they are using the same queries.

Comment: Could you paste some code?

Comment: The only code i have is the populating part. Actually i have no idea how to do filtering , how to start. Would you like me to post the populating of combo box and list?? @CarlosLanderas

Comment: Is ID unique here which means it will only show ONE row when found or it is not unique meaning more than one rows could be shown?

Comment: @Edper  
OK my english isnt really good so pls corret me if i am phrasing it wrongly. The select statement is not really like the example. There is inner join and group by in the statement. So the Query is actually a view. In this form the users can only view and not do anything so filtering might do good for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate `Listview1` on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `comboxbox1` by adding the items you want every time. Example:

```
Private Sub combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    Dim curSelectionCombobox As String = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    For Each item As String In allItems
        If (condition) Then
            ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

With the code above, you get the currently-selected item in `combobox1` (`curSelectionCombobox`) and also iterate through all the elements retrieved from the database and decide (on account of the given condition) which ones should/shouldn't be added. Thus, this approach does not use any filtering, but performs a from-scratch addition of elements every time the selection of `combobox1` changes.

If you want to perform the "filtering" just at form1 load

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    For Each item As String In allItems
        If (condition) Then
            ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want to change the items in the Listview1 at runtime based on various conditions, you should rely on controls allowing multiselection (e.g., checkboxes). Sample code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    If (CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked And CheckBox3.Checked) Then
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        For Each item As String In allItems
            If (condition) Then
                ListView1.Items.Add(item)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Thus, the idea is not adding all the items to the Listbox1 and then filtering them, but just adding the items you want. Where I put "condition" you can call a function performing as complex checks as you wish.

Comment: this was from C# isnt it??? Well What your code does it add to the list view i think but what happens in i select another value in the combobox ?

Comment: Why from C#?! This is VB.NET. This function is called every time the index selected in combobox1 is changed (if you double-click on combobox1 on the designer view, this function would be automatically generated). You get the exact value in the variable curSelectionCombobox. Why don't you implement this solution, test it and understand what does exactly?

Comment: theres a semi colon at the end of listview1.item.add . i want to filter from around 100+ items. Your code Simply adds an item and it does not clear. And i am talking about 10 of those 100+ items having the same id. If i do this it add 1 item. The code i place in my problem is on form load. So on form Load This is displaying.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, a typo :)... My code does not add an item. It adds all the items you want. This code IS CALLED when the user selects a different combobox1 item (you can only select one combobox item at the time). If you want to select various items at the same time, you shouldn't rely on combobox, but on checkboxes, for example; and these will also have associated events. If you don't want to update lists at runtime, you should apply your conditions while populating the Listview1 at form load. I will update my code to account for all these eventualities.

Comment: I will give it a try and see how it works ! (: thanks for your effort i will let you know weather it works.